# Helvetica Neue baseline rendering problem with Firefox/Mac

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, safari

Consider this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height:20px;
    font-size:14px;
}
.a {
    float:left;
}
.b {
    font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="a">something1</div>
    <div class="a b">something2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

On all browsers but Firefox/Mac, it renders correctly, i.e bold and non-bold text are on the same baseline.

On Firefox/Mac, there is a 1px baseline difference between the bold and non-bold texts. See below for screenshot. Left is Safari 3.2.3, right is Firefox 3.0.10.

[alt text http://www.jaanuskase.com/stuff/helveticaneue_ff_safari.png](http://www.jaanuskase.com/stuff/helveticaneue_ff_safari.png)

Is there any way to fix this e.g with some CSS, other than to go quietly cry in the corner and use Arial (which I'd not want to do — I'd stay with Helvetica Neue if I could).

Comment: Switched the font to Helvetica (not Neue) and it appears to be the normal weight that is the problem, not the bold.

Comment: Hmm... when I switch to Helvetica, there doesn't seem to be any baseline problems... so specifically Helvetica Neue is the culprit?

Comment: Right, but when you hit refresh the normal weight moves way up, whereas the bold only moves up a bit, suggesting it has the rendering issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Targeting the line-height can fix this, but not sure if it's the culprit.  If you have CSSEdit (or refresh a lot) you can watch the behavior by incrementing the line-height 1px at a time.

The font-size 14px makes it near impossible.  FF will drop the bold element 1 pixel at some line-heights and safari will drop it at the exact opposites! (i.e. line-height 20px safari drops the bold 1 pixel while firefox renders normally, the opposite of your problem).

*Except* at a 3 pixel line-height, both render the same.  But a 3 pixel line-height is strange, you may need to accommodate by adjusting the margin-top if it goofs up your layout.

```
body {
    font: 14px "Helvetica Neue";
}

.b {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.a {
    line-height: 3px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 9px;
}
```

At a font-size of 13px everything renders the same in both at a 21px line-height (which is closer to a regular line-height.

Playing with different font-sizes and line-heights I'm sure you'll find what you need.

Or hack it, if that's how you roll:

```
body {
    font: 14px "Helvetica Neue";
}

.b {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.a {
    line-height: 21px;
    float: left;

}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {

/* Safari 3.0 and Chrome rules here */

    .a {
        line-height: 20px;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use a licensed version of Helevetica Neue, and I noticed this discrepancy between regular and bold text in buttons. I was able to resolve this by adding `descent-override: 0%;` to my `@font-face` declaration for the bold version. Not supported in every browser as of writing this (no IE 11 or Safari) but Macs usually have Helvetica Neue installed locally so I check for a local version first, and then we are left with just IE 11 unsupported (as usual).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/descent-override

```
// index.scss

/* CDN version - we need to add descent-override to the CDN version only */
@font-face {
  font-family: "font-primary";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src:
    url("<MY-CDN-URL>.woff2")
      format("woff2"),
    url("<MY-CDN-URL>.woff")
      format("woff");
  font-display: swap;
  descent-override: 0%;
}
/* Local version */
@font-face {
  font-family: "font-primary-local";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local("Helvetica Neue Bold");
  font-display: swap;
}


$font-primary: "font-primary-local", "font-primary", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My gut reaction is that the floats are misbehaving. I don't have a Mac, but can you try to do this:

```
<span>something1</span><span class="b">something2</span>
<span class="a">something3</span><span class="a b">something4</span>
```

And see if their baselines are correct?

Comment: I just verified it is the float.  I changed the divs to spans, removed the float, and the bold dropped down a pixel.

Comment: Ok. This whole story just became a whole lot weirder. See http://www.jaanuskase.com/stuff/hnffrendering.zip — it has the above combination plus some others. You can see both the HTML code and its rendering. I am completely mystified as to what is going on at picture 5 — apparently whether or not you have a strong text within one of the divs does not affect the following line, but affects the floated line below it. So yes, something about the floats. (Alas, how can I set vertical text margins without floats?)

Comment: What do you mean with vertical text margins? The "margin-top:" rule is respected. If you want two elements beside each other without removing them from the normal flow you can always use inline elements like span or force your block elements to act like inline with "display: inline".