# Vertical-alignment issues with Helvetica Neue

Tags: css, fonts, vertical-alignment

This is a minor but persistant annoyance with Helvetica Neue (doesn't happen w Arial)

Text that is perfectly vertically aligned will shift downward slightly when any part of the text is bolded. While it's a small shift, it ruins alignment when mixing bold and non-bold text elements side by side.

See http://jsfiddle.net/ZZ3m6/7/ for example.

Even when explicitly setting line-heights, the shift occurs. How can I stop this?

[image]

Comment: Helvetica Neue is a bad choice for the web, I've found. We've had everything from font size issues, to fallback issues (on Windows), an inconsistent line heights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience is not to even bother with Helvetica Neue. Macs come preinstalled with Helvetica anyway and it doesn't have that offsetting issue with bold text that Helvetica Neue has.

Edit: Here's a related question that has some CSS hackery you can use to fix the issue: [Helvetica Neue baseline rendering problem with Firefox/Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917664/helvetica-neue-baseline-rendering-problem-with-firefox-mac?rq=1)

Comment: Ben- thanks for the link/advice- until you and Robert mentioned it had no idea Helvetica Neue was problematic. I switched to font-family:sans-serif and immediately all my vertical alignment issues disappeared in chrome/safari, though now everything shifted upward in Firefox ... :S

Comment: More on H Neue problems: http://angelobeltran.com/blog/articles/helvetica-neue-the-ugly-truth/

Answer (score 0):

The original problem here is fixed in newer versions of Chrome. Tables can still cause trouble when set to `vertical-align: top`: http://jsfiddle.net/nwXHG/

Solution: change to `vertical-align: middle`.